# RInside, Ruby ffi, and missing symbols

Tags: ruby, rcpp, ffi, rinside

I'm attempting to build a set of samples which demonstrate using RInside to provide fast and accurate statistical and numeric functions for Ruby and other languages.  As far as MRI -- the standard Ruby interpreter -- is concerned, this is (relatively) easily solved using RInside and the rice gem.

I'd like to also demo interacting through the Ruby foreign function interface.  When I try to do that, though, I see errors of the form

Could not open library /home/jwlm/rubinius-ffi-test/ffi-code/libsimplemath.so - /home/jwlm/rubinius-ffi-test/ffi-code/libsimplemath.so: undefined symbol: R_FlushConsole

Here's the C++ code:

```
// Simple RInside <-> FFI example
//
// Copyright (C) 2009 Dirk Eddelbuettel
// Copyright (C) 2010 Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois
// Copyright (c) 2016 John Merrill

#include "R.h"
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

namespace {
    const int argc = 0;
    const char *argv = {};
}

extern "C"
bool r_test(double v) {
    RInside R(argc, &argv);

    return true;
}
```

The linker uses every library I can think of: libR, libpcre, ..., libRInside.  (If you really want the full text, I'll include it, but it's uninformative.)

Loading into Ruby 2.3.0 or Rubinius 3.14 fails with the error:

rinside_test.rb: symbol lookup error: /home/jwlm/rubinius-ffi-test/ffi-code/libsimplemath.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7RInsideC1EiPKPKcbbb

This would make perfect sense if I weren't already including libRInside, but I am.

Comment: `_ZN7RInsideC1EiPKPKcbbb` corresponds to `RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool, bool, bool)` - what command are you using to compile this?

Comment: Which isn't far from the ctor `RInside(const int argc, const char* const argv[], const bool loadRcpp=true, const bool verbose=false, const bool interactive=false);`.  But the example is still incomplete and I am not sure if/how we can help.

Comment: Forgive me, yes, I realized that it was the constructor for RInside.

Comment: Here's the linker command line.

g++ -shared 
    -lpthread 
    -Wl,-soname,libsimplemath 
    -o libsimplemath.so 
    -L/usr/lib/R/lib
    -lR
    -lpcre
    -llzma
    -lbz2
    -lz
    -lrt
    -ldl
    -lm 
    -lblas
    -llapack
    -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib 
    -lRInside
    -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib
    -lstdc++
    rinside_rice_grain.o

Comment: And here's the actual compiler command line:

g++ -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/ 
    -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include 
    -I/usr/share/R/include 
    -Wall 
    -fPIC 
    -g 
    -O2     -fstack-protector 
    --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 
    -Wformat 
    -Werror=format-security 
    -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 
    -std=c++11   -c rinside_rice_grain.cpp

Comment: I'm running Rcpp version 0.12.1 and RInside version 0.2.13.  What else do you need, Dirk?

Comment: Hmpf.  I know next to nothing about Ruby but this should work.  We have embedded R in many other places.  Do you have a complete repo somewheer to look at?  The commands you quoted look fine.